# receive screen touch events

Tags: android, screen

Is there any way to receive when screen is touched in android. I need to receive a broadcast message when screen is touched from one of my listener. It does not matter in which screen the phone is whether it is in my application screen or any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible for normal app. Your app need super user privilege to catch those kind of events.

Comment: thnx.but what do you mean by super user privilege. Is it mean that my app needs device admin permission.

Comment: Yes. The device must be root, and the user also needs to grant super user privilege to your device. That's the only way you can access the system events.